# Entrust CA and Intermedita CA certificates from windows 2008 are getting deleted automatically

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, certificate

we got one strange issue where the Entrust CA and Intermedita CA certificates from windows 2008 are getting deleted automatically and we need to find why is this happening can anyone help on below

i have checked in security logs but couldnot find any thing .

do we have any specific location where the certificate logs are stored to get more info ?

any clue why the certificates are getting automatically deleted?

Regards,
Vikas Chandra.C

Comment: we got the issue resolved, Upon Entrust Certificate Root Chain installation, the Entrust Root CA was incorrectly placed in the Enterprise Store and not in the Physical Store of Trusted Root on the server ,we have reinstalled the cert on server which solved the issued